# Is there a fetch for local repository only?

Tags: git

Is there a way to do a fetch in a local-only repository? For example, if I wanted to bring in changes from a feature branch into master without doing a merge?

In other words, there is no remote repository connected with this repository. It exists solely on my machine. There's no particular reason I'm asking other than curiosity.

Comment: What is the problem with merging feature branch into master?

Comment: Nothing really, just curious if there was a way

Comment: [Fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) is used to bring in info from a "remote" repo (which, despite the name, could be another local directory). This just assumes it is a mirror copy of your local repo, so it's intended use it not what you describe necessarily, but you could use `git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>` to do something similar, but it doesn't sound like what you are intending to do. 

Why do you not want to use merge? You could also use [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for this if you are simply exploring for other tools.

Comment: I don't have a particular reason, was just wondering. I didn't know it could be another local directory. So if you put that as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: I would agree with @TopherBuckley - `git fetch` is really a remote-oriented operation, but `git rebase` or ([`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) if you want to be more manual) might provide the functionality you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git fetch` has two main jobs, one of them big (or biggish) and hard (-ish), and one of them small and easy.  The big hard part is getting actual commits and other objects—all of which are labeled by hash IDs—from some other repository, in an efficient manner.  The small-and-easy job is to update some names—usually *remote-tracking* names like `origin/master`—based on information learned while doing the big job.

Since your repository already has every commit that your repository has, pointing `git fetch` at your own repository makes the big hard job trivial, leaving it only with the small-and-easy job.  You *can* do this:

```
git fetch .
```

directs `git fetch` to use `.` as the URL-or-remote-name.  Git treats this as a sort of `file://` URL, but without the `//`, so that it names the current directory as the local file in which the other repository lives.  If the repository is in the current directory, that connects your Git repository to itself.  It then lists out any commits it has that it doesn't have—which is of course no commits—and therefore has no commits to update.

Having updated no commits, it goes on to its smaller job, of updating various names.  The names to be updated are those you provide via *refspecs*.  Normally, you'd run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and `remote.origin.fetch` would provide these refspec arguments.   Since you didn't use `origin`, *you* have to provide the refspecs.

The second-simplest form of refspec is spelled as `src:dst`, where the *`src`* and *`dst`* parts are *refs*.  The colon in the middle is required in this second-simplest form.<sup>1</sup>  The source ref is, typically, a branch name like `master`—or its fully-spelled out form, `refs/heads/master`—and the destination is typically a *remote-tracking name* like `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

When using `git fetch .`, it doesn't make sense to use remote-tracking names.  It *does* make sense to use *branch* names, though.  Here, a refspec like `master:develop` actually makes sense.

In this second-simplest form, Git reads the commit hash ID associated with the source name from the source Git (which is yourself) and does a sort of careful, check-ful update of the destination name in the destination Git (which is again yourself).  If the update is allowed, it happens.  If not, it doesn't.

You can add the `--force` flag, or a leading plus sign in front of the refspec, to force the update even if the checks fail.  So `git fetch . +master:develop` and `git fetch --force . master:develop` mean the same thing here: read `master` from the source Git and use the resulting hash ID to force-update `develop` in the destination Git.  This will wipe out any existing `develop` that you have and put in a `develop` that points to the *same* commit as `master`.

In other words, this does the same thing as `git branch -f develop master`.  The latter is more obvious and therefore the command that you should use instead.  (Still, a full description of what happens here is useful.)

*Without* the leading plus or `--force`, this `git fetch` does something that is harder to express with a simpler Git command.  The only other thing built in to Git that achieves the same result is to use `git push` similarly:

```
git push . master:develop
```

has exactly the same overall effect as `git fetch . master:develop`.  With `git push`, your Git calls itself up, *gives* itself any commits it has that it doesn't already have (i.e., none), and asks itself to update, gently and carefully, its `develop` to match its own `master`—the same gentle update that `git fetch . master:develop` performs after *getting* no commits.

So, both of these commands have this effect.  The numbered steps determine whether the gentle/polite update is to be accepted or rejected:

1. Test whether the branch name `develop` exists.  If not, proceed: the name-update request is accepted.
2. Test whether `develop` is the current branch.  If so, reject the request (but see configuration settings for `git push`, or the `-u` flag for `git fetch`).
3. Get the hash ID from the current branch setting.  Test whether the new proposed commit ID has the current commit hash ID as an ancestor.  That is, test whether this update is a *fast forward* operation.  If so, accept the request.
4. The request is not a fast-forward: reject the request.  (This test is skipped/replaced with "accept" under `--force` or `+`.)

If the request is accepted, the command will now replace the hash ID stored in the name with the new proposed hash ID.  Hence either `git push . master:develop` or `git fetch . master:develop` has the effect of fast-forwarding our `develop` to match our `master`, provided we're not on `develop` now, and that fast-forwarding is possible.

To do this without `git fetch` or `git push`, the straightforward way is:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --ff-only master
```

which is actually how I normally do it—this mucking-about with `git push . master:develop` is most too tricky to bother with.  (I use `git push` on the rare occasion when I really want to avoid the checkout, to avoid messing with my current work-tree.  These days, you can use `git worktree add` to avoid messing with *this* work-tree, but that takes a little more work than the hacky `git push .` trick.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The simplest form omits the colon.  This form has some uses for some cases when getting commits from some *other* Git, and more use cases in `git push` where you're typically *giving* commits to some other Git.  But if you're pointing your Git at itself, those use cases never apply, and the simplest form becomes useless.  Hence all the concentration here on the second-simplest form.